# VBoxSVC.exe постоянно накапливает RAM, как это ограничеть

Tags: virtualbox

На Windows 7 постоянно запущено 18 - 20 виртуальных машин, при этом процесс VBoxSVC.exe постоянно увеличивает потребление RAM.
За несколько дней накапливается >2гб. После перезапуска всех машин память этого процесса опять обнуляется. У кого-то получалось решить эту проблему?